# PCA: How to get eigenvalues from principal() R function

Tags: r, pca

Given this line of code:

`pca <- principal(x, nfactors = 7, rotate= "oblimin")`

where *x* is my already centred data (mood items) and I am performing a PCA using the principal() function in R with an *oblimin* rotation (nature of the data is multilevel - ESM). I get the following output:

```
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = x, nfactors = 7, rotate = "oblimin")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
                   TC1   TC3   TC7   TC4   TC2   TC6   TC5   h2      u2 com
animado_cnt       0.96 -0.01 -0.06  0.02 -0.02  0.00 -0.04 0.88 0.11936 1.0
nervioso_cnt      0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  1.00  0.00  0.00 1.00 0.00064 1.0
contento_cnt      0.81  0.10  0.07 -0.09  0.00  0.10 -0.03 0.85 0.15419 1.1
triste_cnt        0.00  0.01  0.00  1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 1.00 0.00172 1.0
energico_cnt      0.63 -0.26  0.21  0.00  0.04 -0.11  0.07 0.77 0.22673 1.7
irritable_cnt    -0.01  0.01 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.99 1.00 0.00290 1.0
relajado_cnt      0.01 -0.02  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.99  0.00 0.99 0.00727 1.0
cansado_cnt       0.00  0.98  0.01  0.02  0.01 -0.03  0.02 0.98 0.02198 1.0
entusiasmado_cnt  0.00  0.01  0.99  0.00 -0.01  0.01 -0.02 0.99 0.01207 1.0

                       TC1  TC3  TC7  TC4  TC2  TC6  TC5
SS loadings           2.15 1.09 1.14 1.04 1.01 1.01 1.01
Proportion Var        0.24 0.12 0.13 0.12 0.11 0.11 0.11
Cumulative Var        0.24 0.36 0.49 0.60 0.71 0.83 0.94
Proportion Explained  0.25 0.13 0.13 0.12 0.12 0.12 0.12
Cumulative Proportion 0.25 0.38 0.52 0.64 0.76 0.88 1.00

 With component correlations of 
      TC1   TC3   TC7   TC4   TC2   TC6   TC5
TC1  1.00 -0.39  0.67 -0.46 -0.11  0.25 -0.38
TC3 -0.39  1.00 -0.37  0.22  0.01 -0.10  0.22
TC7  0.67 -0.37  1.00 -0.34 -0.06  0.22 -0.30
TC4 -0.46  0.22 -0.34  1.00  0.22 -0.26  0.42
TC2 -0.11  0.01 -0.06  0.22  1.00 -0.41  0.28
TC6  0.25 -0.10  0.22 -0.26 -0.41  1.00 -0.35
TC5 -0.38  0.22 -0.30  0.42  0.28 -0.35  1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.1
Test of the hypothesis that 7 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.03 
 with the empirical chi square  147.52  with prob <  NA 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.99
```

How can I calculate the eigenvalues?

According to the R documentation on principal() function, the eigenvalues can be extracted by running:

```
pca$values
```

which results in:

```
[1] 4.0251460 1.4366822 0.7544647 0.7215495 0.5964269 0.5362665 0.3826062 0.3266584 0.2201997
```

Are those the eigenvalues?

I have tried adapting the line of code with the *principal* function (setting no rotation) and compare it to other PCA functions like *prcomp* and *princomp*, but the eigenvalues I obtain are different. For example:

```
pca <- principal(x, nfactors = 7, rotate= "none") 
pca$values
>[1] 4.0251460 1.4366822 0.7544647 0.7215495 0.5964269 0.5362665 0.3826062 0.3266584 0.2201997

pca_2 <- prcomp(x)
pca_2$sdev^2
>[1] 10.3433640  4.1025390  2.3719063  1.7041451  1.6689658  1.2126279  1.0276039  0.8733053  0.4886626
```

Why are the eigenvalues different? Do I need to multiply by a constant? Which one?

How can I justify using the function *principal* that I have taken those factors with an eigenvalue higher than 1 if the eigenvalues differ between methods? This is, if I was using the function *principal* I would only consider 2 factors, while with the function *prcomp* I would need 7.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answer on how to do this with other R packages can be found on [this stackoverflow posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086661/r-principal-get-eigenvalues-of-factors)
I'm not marking this as a duplicate because this question does seem to ask if there is a mathematical way to calculate the eigenvalues. I don't know of a way but want to leave open if others can figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

OK so I got the answer to my own question. Hope it is useful.

The functions *prcomp* and *princomp* in R automatically work with the covariances matrix, while *principal* works with the correlation matrix. Therefore, changing the default setting of the *scale* and *cor* arguments (in *prcomp* and *princomp*, repectively) should result in the same eigenvalues as using the *principal* function.

[Note here I use "mood_items" instead of "x" to refer to the data in the code]

```
pca_1 <- principal(mood_items, nfactors = 2, rotate= "none")
pca_1$values
pca_2 <- princomp(mood_items, cor=TRUE)
pca_2$sdev^2
pca_3 <- prcomp(mood_items, scale=TRUE)
pca_3$sdev^2
```

```
> pca_1 <- principal(mood_items, nfactors = 2, rotate= "none")
> pca_1$values
[1] 4.0251460 1.4366822 0.7544647 0.7215495 0.5964269 0.5362665 0.3826062 0.3266584 0.2201997
> pca_2 <- princomp(mood_items, cor=T)
> pca_2$sdev^2
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5    Comp.6    Comp.7    Comp.8    Comp.9 
4.0251460 1.4366822 0.7544647 0.7215495 0.5964269 0.5362665 0.3826062 0.3266584 0.2201997 
> pca_3 <- prcomp(mood_items, scale=TRUE)
> pca_3$sdev^2
[1] 4.0251460 1.4366822 0.7544647 0.7215495 0.5964269 0.5362665 0.3826062 0.3266584 0.2201997
```

We can, then, conclude that there are two principal components in our data with eigenvalues > than 1. To reassure my analysis, I have also ran a parallel analysis arriving at the same results:

```
parallel <- fa.parallel(mood_items)
> Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  2
```

[image: Parallel Analysis Scree Plot]